# c++: запись файла в несуществующую папку

Tags: c++, файлы, stl, path, fstream

Подскажите пожалуйста наилучший способ как записать файл в некоторую папку `folder1\folder2\...\folderN`, если в наличии только папка `folder1\folder2\...\folderM`.

При этом запись выполняется с помощью `std::ofstream`.

Понятно, что задачу можно решить в лоб - распарсить путь к файлу и проверить существует ли каждая папка в пути и если нет - создать ее.

Но может/наверное существует более простой путь для решения этой задачи?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы делал так - воспользовался стандартной библиотекой `<filesystem>` и создавал бы каталог с помощью [`create_directories()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) не глядя, есть ли уже такой каталог или нет. Нет - создаст, есть - ну и хорошо :)

А потом бы создавал файл.

Все равно проверка существования 100% гарантии не дает - между проверкой и созданием файла кто-то другой может каталог и стереть :)

**Update**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::error_code e;
    std::cout << std::filesystem::create_directories("G:\\Tmp\\Test\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc",e) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::filesystem::create_directory("G:\\Tmp\\Test\\zzz",e) << std::endl;
}
```

VC++ 2017 15.9.7

Скомпилировало, работает.

Comment: вроде студия 2017, и инклюд библиотеки он видит и внутри этой библиотеки нужные функции есть, а все равно на `std::filesystem::create_directory(path);` ругается, типа нет в std такой функции :(

Comment: Проверьте правильность написания... В ответ добавил код, который только что скомпилировал и выполнил. Работает...

Comment: @Zhihar Убедитесь, что стандарт выставлен на C++17

Comment: @VVT, обновился до 15.9.7 (было 15.2), в настройках проекта выставил Windows SDK Version 10.0.17763.0 - не помогло. Создал новый проект - все равно на filesystem ругается :( Может где-то дополнительно надо C++17 выставить?

Comment: `/std:c++17` выставьте. Или `/std:latest`